# R plot: Legend background size

Tags: r, plot, legend, scatter-plot

I am making a plot (scatter plot, specifically) using R, and noticed that the background size of the legend is unnecessarily big (as shown below):

[image]

Is there any way that I can reduce the area?

I tried to change `cex`, but it reduced not only the area but also the font size. I want to keep the font size, but reduce the legend area.

Just in case, I attached the code of the legend that I have used:

```
legend(x="bottomleft", legend = c("Survived (0)", "Died (1)"), 
         col=c(1:length(levels(Noadr.for.plot2$Death))), pch = c(19, 17),
         y.intersp = 0.4,
         bg = "gray")
```

[UPDATED]
Here, the revised plot. I was able to modify the text width, but not the height (as shown below):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
attach(mtcars)
plot(wt, mpg, main="Scatterplot Example",
     xlab="Car Weight ", ylab="Miles Per Gallon ", pch=19)
# op <- par(cex = 1)

text = c("Survived (0)", "Died (1)")
cex_val = 1

legend(x="bottomleft", legend = text,
       pch = c(19, 17), cex=cex_val,
       y.intersp = 1,
       bg = "gray",
       text.width = strwidth(text)[1]*cex_val)
```

Part of the legend width is determined by the longest width of the labels you use, which is calculated via `strwidth` so by setting it to the text width you can reduce the box while keeping the font size.

Comment: @@David S Hi, David! Thanks for the comment. I successfully worked! However, I was able to modify the text width, not the height. Please see the figure above (I uploaded the updated figure). I assumed that there will be a function something like text.height, but unfortunately it does not exist...